# tensorflow No module named "_pywrap_tensorflow_internal"

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, tensorflow

Всем привет. Не запускается программа на python с tesnorflow. Вот ошибка:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
swig_import_helper
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', 
[dirname(__file__)])
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", 
line 296, in find_module
raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
<module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in 
swig_import_helper
import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:  

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "root.py", line 10, in <module>
from keras.models import Sequential #ANN architecture
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import utils
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import conv_utils
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\keras\utils\
conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
from .. import backend as K
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .load_backend import epsilon
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\keras\backend\load_backend.py", line 90, in <module>
from .tensorflow_backend import *
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37- 
32\lib\sitepackages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site 
packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused 
import
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
swig_import_helper
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', 
[dirname(__file_
_)])
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\imp.py", 
line 296, in find_module
raise ImportError(_ERR_MSG.format(name), name=name)
ImportError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
<module>
_pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- 
packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 20, in 
swig_import_helper
import _pywrap_tensorflow_internal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/errors

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

Версия Windows: 8 64 bit
Оперативная память 3 gb
Python Version: 3.7.4
Tensoflow :1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

Для всех кто будет искать этот вопрос в будущем, переустановите python на 3.6, tensorflow на 1.6.0

Comment: Почему решились на такой downgrade?

Comment: Я так понял из за того что tensorflow не хочет корректно работать с python > 3.7

Comment: А питон 3.6 не поддерживает Tensoflow 1.12.0? Пробовали?